# How to package a NetBeans Java project for Ubuntu

Tags: java, oracle, swing, deployment

I'm in final year of my B.Tech. For a project, I have created an multilingual dictionary in Java (with NetBeans 6.7.1) in which we can search a word's meaning, its synonyms, antonyms and an example, or if it's not available then we can add a new word in the database.

I have used Swing and Oracle database 10g for word storage and external jar rs2xml which is not provided by Oracle by default. I have many more ideas in my mind which I will apply to this project after my finals.

Now I want to publish it on the Ubuntu Software Center as an open source project so others can also share new ideas and make it successful.

I have no idea how to convert a NetBeans Java project into a Debian package.

Is there any criteria that needs to be fulfilled in order to publish a project on Software Center?

I assume I will have to back up a database table and check if the user has Java or Oracle installed on their computer or prompt them to install these first etc.

Comment: jar works itself.. does not need to create debian package for ubuntu.

Comment: than how to uplad jar on software center

Comment: and i want to make it open source project so where i have to put source code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Reference site. It gives you step-by-step information about create .deb for your swing application.

[Swing applications deployment on Linux: DEB packages](http://www.richjavablog.com/2012/02/swing-applications-deployment-on-linux.html)

DEB packages are created using dpkg-deb tool, found in most Linux distributions

**For updated questions.**

[Uploading your app on ubuntu software center.](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/apps/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/my-apps-packages/)

Thanks..

Comment: but i have created my project on net-beans which is installed on windows, so am i suppose to first copy these code in another ide installed on ubuntu than create jar file again or this one will also work fine.

Comment: no need to create jar just export project from the windows and import into the ubuntu's netbeans.

Comment: and how i check if user already have java and oracle 10g installed on his computer and if not than prompt him to install these first

Comment: for that create new question on forum. it's not one comment answer for your question. and you must manually install the 10g in client system.. no any other option for that if it is not installed on client machine.

Comment: ok i think now i am getting it , first i need to export my project into other ide installed on ubuntu , then use the command dpkg-deb it will create a deb file of my project , correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @shrikant.sharma :yes exactly first import your project into the ubuntu system. then doing as my answer said!! if you found my answer helpful then accept and upvote it. Thanks..

Comment: ok assume i have created deb , than how to upload it on software center and to make it open source where i have to put source code

Comment: @shrikant.sharma: check my updated answer!! it gives you whole information from starting!! Thanks..

Comment: @shrikant.sharma: did you check my updated answer? getting your answer?

Answer (score -1):

> I have used swing ,

For deploying Java desktop apps., the best option is usually to install the app. using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  JWS works on Windows, OS X & *nix.

> ..oracle data base 10g for words storage

Install it using an `installer-desc` JNLP (a JWS launch file).  They are run once on install, and a 2nd time on uninstall.

> ..and external jar rs2xml which is not provided by oracle by default, ..

Add them to the run-time class-path using a `jar` element in the JNLP.